# Docker Compose hostname command not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm unable to get the Docker Compose [`hostname`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir) command to work.

I'm running a simple `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis1:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    hostname: redis1host
  redis2:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    hostname: redis2host
```

Once I run this with `docker-compose up`, I should be able to run `docker-compose exec redis1 /bin/ash` and then `ping redis2host` to talk to the other Redis container, but the ping just doesn't reach its destination. I can ping the other Redis container with `ping redis2`.

`ping redishost2` should work, no?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `hostname` directive simply sets the hostname inside the container (that is, the name you get back in response to the `hostname` or `uname -n` commands). It does not result in a DNS alias for the service.  For that, you want the [aliases](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases) directive. Since that directive is per-network, you need to be explicit about networks rather than using the compose default, for example:

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis1:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    hostname: redis1host
    networks:
      redis:
        aliases:
          - redis1host
  redis2:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    hostname: redis2host
    networks:
      redis:
        aliases:
          - redis2host

networks:
  redis:
```

Comment: If you don't want to add use network in your docker-compose, just using `networks:` `default` `aliases` ... would also works