# haproxy docker-compose hostname not resolving

Tags: docker, docker-compose, haproxy

For the sake of brevity and confidentiality, I am asking the question with renamed data and only including the relevant components of the issue.

My configurations are the following:

my docker-compose.yml file:

```
services:
  my_service:
    hostname: my_hostname
    image: my_django_image
    command: gunicorn --bind :8000 my_app.wsgi:application
    ports:
    - '8000:8000'
```

and haproxy.conf

```
backend my_backend
    balance roundrobin
    option httpchk GET /_haproxychk
    server my_backend nb:8000 check inter 15000ms
```

I am getting the error:

```
 [ALERT] 298/044001 (1) : parsing [/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:101] : 'server 
 my_backend' : could not resolve address 'my_hostname'
```

Can anybody tell me what I am configuring incorrectly? If I take away the 'my_hostname' part, django will give me an error saying that 0.0.0.0:8000 does is not a subdomain of the host... an annoying middleware issue that I was trying to remove from logging every time the haproxy check happens

Comment: Remove hostname and use docker networks

Comment: Share your haproxy.cfg file

Comment: This is the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46239662/docker-compose-hostname-command-not-working

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a resolvers section to your haproxy cfg after the "defaults" section, so that the docker DNS will be used:

```
resolvers docker
        parse-resolv-conf
```

Also, set the haproxy to not confirm backend addresses on startup as the container hostname to address resolution might not be setup yet (In the "defaults" section):

```
default-server init-addr last,libc,none
```